# magento 2: How to edit a cronjob/crontab schedule in the admin backend

Tags: magento2, cron, backend, crontab, schedule

I have been searching almost all day and i can't seem to find how i can change a cronjob/crontab its settings/schedule without using cache:reflush after changing the crontab.xml file.

This is so I can change a cronjob his schedule while the shop is running and i don't need to reflush the cache.

I think the cronjob's schedule get's saved in the cache but can't seem to find how not to do this...

so how can i do this?

EDIT: i can probably do this like this: [How to set cronjob dynamic schedule from database in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139248/how-to-set-cronjob-dynamic-schedule-from-database-in-magento-2)

Answer (score 3):

I did something simple using cron schedule expressions like: `*/5 * * * *`

app/code/My/Module/etc/crontab.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="processSomething" instance="My\Module\Cron\Something" method="execute">
            <config_path>some_config/cron/schedule</config_path>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

app/code/My/Module/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Config/etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="some_config" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="300" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Hello!</label>
            <tab>mymodule</tab>
            <resource>My_Module::config</resource>
            <group id="cron" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Crons</label>
                <field id="schedule" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Cron schedule</label>
                    <comment>Fromat: * * * * *</comment>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Comment: Working on Magento 2.3.4 Commerce